# jquery next plus toggle is not working. Is this a bug?

Tags: jquery, toggle

The following code does not work in IE7 or IE8...does anyone have any ideas as to why? Thanks!

```
$('.change_settings_btn').live('click', function(){
    var link = $(this);
    link.next('.change_settings_box').toggle(0, function(){
        link.toggleClass('change_on');
    });
});
```

Comment: Your HTML would help, but maybe try using `nextAll()` instead of `next()`

Comment: Are you sure you want to toggle the class of the button? `link.toggleClass('change_on');` doesn't change the next box, but the btn itself. To toggle the box you should use the code provided by Jason.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this:

```
$('.change_settings_btn').live('click', function(){
    var link = $(this);
    link.next('.change_settings_box').toggleClass('change_on');
});
```

Although I can't say for sure because I don't know what your HTML looks like or what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Ah, ok maybe I didn't explain this well enough.  This is toggling the visibility of the .change_settings_box and then also changing the class of the .change_settings_button.  It works fine in all browsers except IE7 and IE8.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have multiple change settings menus on one page.  I am trying to toggle the visibility of the .change_settings_box and then also toggle the class of the .change_settings_button when its clicked.  Really simple.  Its just not working in IE7 or 8...weird.